# How to change the time format displayed in the chart?

Tags: angular, chart.js

My schedule uses time to display the results. But the time in the graph is displayed in this format: `HH:mm:ss`.

And I want to do in this format: `HH:mm`.

I tried to use the `moment`, but when I add a function `format`, an error occurs.

> Invalid date

Is it possible to fix this somehow?

```
...
    stateTimeConfig.labels = data.map(item => moment(item.state_time).format('HH:mm'))
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use momentJs you have to use an entire date string, you could just append any date to it and it should work for you:

```
    stateTimeConfig.labels = data.map(item => moment('2019-01-01 '+ item.state_time).format('HH:mm'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass specific parser string to moment() if you know the format that you want to parse.

See documentation at [MomentJs Parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).
You can see an example of using it at [Example codepen](https://codepen.io/donatasd/pen/dyydrNv).

Solution:

```
stateTimeConfig.labels = data.map(item => (
  moment(item.state_time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm')
))
```